# Access nested dict key in following style: selected = {k: tweets[i]._json[k] for k in {'created_at', 'id', 'full_text'}

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

After hours of research I am kind of lost. No Problem seems to match mine.

The problems is the following:
I have a JSON containing all sorts of information about a tweet. Much of which is nested, meaning a JSON as a value for a key. The keys inside of the { } are the keys of which I want to retrieve the key-value pair. With 'first level keys' there is no problem whatsoever. It retrieves them just fine. But I dont know how to acces the 'deeper level' keys. I know how to access a lower level value, namely with dictObject['FirstLevelKey']['SecondLevelKey]. The Problem though is that this returns the value of this certain key and not the key itself. I somehow need to tell the code where exactly to find the key inside the brackets { }.

As an example: There is a 'First level' key inside of my main JSON(tweets[i]._json) named 'user' which has a JSON as a value containing the key 'geo_enabled'. How could I tell my Programm to retrieve this key the same way as my 'first level' keys 'created_at', 'id', 'full_text'?
I hope I was able to express my problem in an understandable manner. Thanks in advance.

`selected = {k: tweets[i]._json[k] for k in {'created_at', 'id', 'full_text', tweets[i]._json['user']['geo_enabled']}` obviously doesn't work

Comment: can you provide some example json?

Comment: yeah sure, I posted it below

Comment: do you want to flatten all the nested keys automatically without having to specify the structure?

Comment: hmmm yes flattening is a very good idea! It would remove the problem of needing to access a nested key-value pair. Since I dont really care how exactly it is nested or part of which dict it was. Is there any handy function for flattening dicts?

Comment: but there might be a problem with that... This dict is only a shortend version of the original dict. In the original dict some keys like 'id' occur multiple time in differend 'layer'. When flattening the dict this would lead to ambigiuity of keys ...

Comment: in this case it shouldn't lead to ambiguity, I have been considering writing a recursive function to automatically flatten a dict until all the keys are exhausted, maybe I'll give it a try, there are probably many packages out there than can do this though

Comment: nah it's all good man. Thanks a lot for the idea though! Helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

{"created_at": "Thu Dec 10 14:12:18 +0000 2020",

```
 "id": 1337804994,
 "id_str": "1337037427630804994",
 "full_text": "hello",
 "user": {
     "id": 25360913,
     "id_str": "25360913",
     "translator_type": "none"
 },
 "geo": False,
 "coordinates": False,
 "retweeted": False,
 "lang": "de"
 }
```

Comment: so how would I make my code know I want to have the key-value-pair ['user'][id] in my result JSON?

Comment: you technically already have [user][id] in the json...

Answer (score -1):

Here is some info about accessing nested dictionary values: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-dictionary/

You can do it this way very simply:

```py
tweet_dict = {
    "created_at": "Thu Dec 10 14:12:18 +0000 2020",
    "id": 1337804994,
    "id_str": "1337037427630804994",
    "full_text": "hello",
    "user": {
        "id": 25360913,
        "id_str": "25360913",
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": False,
    "coordinates": False,
    "retweeted": False,
    "lang": "de"
}
```

```py
new_dict = {
    **tweet_dict, # unpack the tweet dict
    'user_id': tweet_dict['user']['id'], # add the user_id key
}

# pretty print the output
from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_dict)
```

Or without creating a new dict:

```py
tweet_dict['user_id'] = tweet_dict['user']['id'], # add the user_id key
```

Output:

```py
{'coordinates': False,
 'created_at': 'Thu Dec 10 14:12:18 +0000 2020',
 'full_text': 'hello',
 'geo': False,
 'id': 1337804994,
 'id_str': '1337037427630804994',
 'lang': 'de',
 'retweeted': False,
 'user': {'id': 25360913, 'id_str': '25360913', 'translator_type': 'none'},
 'user_id': 25360913}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time! I somehow wanted to stick to the code that I had and only find out how to access the nested keys to keep my code more uniform. But I may have to just hardcode these particular keys as in your answer...

Comment: but thinking about it, what I would have done otherwise is a form of hardcoding anyways, there is no way I would be able to tell my code to add a certain nested key without him telling first where exactly in the dict to find it (without looping)